# open source free print framework for Java GUI application

Tags: java

Searching for an easy to use, open source and free printing framework for a Java GUI application. If you have any experience using different frameworks, please suggest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: After some searching found Jasper reporting framework which also comesup with the designer app. BIRT is another good framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching found Jasper reporting framework which also comesup with the designer app. BIRT is another good framework.